# How to sort a dynamic range in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel table called AnimeList, where I have listed all the anime I have finished watching along with their info. The table has the following headers:

Name, Main Genre, Genre2, Genre3, Rating, Seasons, Episodes, Mins/Episode, Status.

I have created also created a range which includes the distinct genres in this table with the number of values for each distinct genre.

I used the following formula to get the distinct values from the 3 genre columns in my table

```
IFERROR(IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$G$6:$G$58, MATCH(0, INDEX(COUNTIF($P$7:P7, Sheet1!$G$6:$G$58),), 0)), INDEX(Sheet1!$H$6:$H$58, MATCH(0, INDEX(COUNTIF($P$7:P7, Sheet1!$H$6:$H$58),), 0))), INDEX(Sheet1!$I$6:$I$58, MATCH(0, INDEX(COUNTIF($P$7:P7, Sheet1!$I$6:$I$58),), 0)))
```

In short this formula uses index match to get the distinct values in one column and then once it runs out of distinct values and returns N/A(Error), the IFERROR function directs it to another column where it does the same and so on till the 3rd column.

After this I counted how many of anime are there with the given genre next to it using the following formula:

```
COUNTIF($G$6:$I$58, P8)
```

Here $G$6:$I$58 is the 3 genre columns in my table and P8 contains the genre we are looking for which becomes P9 P10 etc as I drag it down.

Now I wanted to sort this range in descending order so I tried converting it to table and use the sort filter but nothing happened.

Is there any way to sort this range? If not, is there any other way with which if I find the distinct values I can sort it?

I know about the UNIQUE function in excel but it is only available in Microsoft 365 which I dont have, I have Microsoft Office Home and Student 2019.

**Edit:**
So, I saw that there was no way to do this without VBA so I learned some basic VBA and wrote this code that will return a 2d array with the genres in sorted order.

```
Function CountAndSortGenre() As Variant()

    Dim size As Integer: size = Range("AnimeList[Main Genre]").Rows.Count
    
    ReDim genreExtract((size * 3) - 1) As String
    
    Dim i As Integer: i = 0
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Range("AnimeList[Main Genre]")
        genreExtract(i) = cell.Value
        i = i + 1
    Next
    For Each cell In Range("AnimeList[Genre - 2]")
        genreExtract(i) = cell.Value
        i = i + 1
    Next
    For Each cell In Range("AnimeList[Genre - 3]")
        genreExtract(i) = cell.Value
        i = i + 1
    Next
    
    Dim distinctGenres As New Dictionary
    Dim genre As Variant
    For Each genre In genreExtract
        If distinctGenres.exists(genre) Then
            distinctGenres(genre) = distinctGenres(genre) + 1
        Else
            distinctGenres.Add genre, 1
        End If
    Next
    
    size = distinctGenres.Count
    Erase genreExtract
    
    ReDim sortedGenres(size - 1, 1) As Variant
    For i = 0 To distinctGenres.Count - 1
        sortedGenres(i, 0) = distinctGenres.Keys(i)
        sortedGenres(i, 1) = distinctGenres.Items(i)
    Next i
    
    distinctGenres.RemoveAll
    QuickSort sortedGenres, 0, size - 1
    
    CountAndSortGenre = sortedGenres

End Function
```

Here I have implemented QuickSort function too but I did not include that code here as that is irrelevant.

The only problem now is that I cant find a way to populate a range of cells with this 2d array output. If I do something like this inside a cell

```
=CountAndSortGenre()
```

All I get is the first item of the array and I cant get the other elements by dragging the result. I am sure I am missing something very trivial here as this should not be so hard to do after this.

How do I get this 2d array to output into a range of cells

Comment: If VBA is an option the solution is pretty simple.

Comment: Its not like its not an option, only that I dont know much about it yet. If there is no way to do this without VBA, I can definitely learn basic VBA.

Comment: With either VBA or Power Query, you can easily combine your three columns into a single array of unique entries, and then sort them.  An option for your worksheet would be, before sorting the sheet, do a copy/paste special: Values.  The reason your current method isn't working is because, even after sorting, the formulas are still referring to the original, unsorted values.

Comment: But if I copy/paste special the values wont it lose its dynamisms. Like if I add another entry to the list the other list should get automatically updated. Without formulas and only values this dynamic behavior would be lost, wouldn't it.

Comment: Yes, it will.  And without it, you won't be able to sort it. I was providing an option whereby you could avoid using Power Query or VBA.  Of course, with either of those, you'd have to trigger a refresh using Event code, in order to have it update when you changed things. Or go with O365. Or maybe use a helper column once you get your unique list.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I edited the question and added some VBA code that I wrote after you suggested me to use VBA yesterday. I am just facing a small issue. Can you please help

Comment: Two methods: 1) Use the Index function to return the desired element of the array in each cell.  2) [Enter the formula over an array of cells with **ctrl+shift+enter**](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwizo-S7iKXtAhUtTDABHdV5DFgQFjABegQIAxAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fsupport.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Foffice%2Fvideo-array-formulas-8ff8257a-b28e-4e81-b4f8-30f793412dfa&usg=AOvVaw37cnlS2-6zxrsZvy8k_6Tc).  I am surprised that Excel 2019 doesn't automatically spill the results.